# scikit learn SVM stop and access during training

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I am using scikitlearn to train a SVM. I was wondering it would be possible to pause training every so often to test the current model's accuracy on my validation set. Ultimately I want to generate a validation accuracy curve. using .Fit() trains an SVM all the way through but that just gives me one accuracy data point at the end

Answer (score 0):

There is a little trick you can use actually.

You can play on the parameter `max_iter` of your `SVC` classifier.
For instance, you can get multiple classifiers with different number of iterations.

Here is what you can do :

```
import numpy as np

for i in np.arange(10, 1000, 100):
    svm = SVC(max_iter=i) # and your other parameters
    svm.fit(X, y)
    ... # here retrieve your metrics
```

Doing so will show you how the classifier performs at different level of the training.

Comment: I actually tried this before I posted on Stack Overflow, but I recall reading somewhere that called .Fit() would remove the weights it had already learned. I would want .Fit() to pick up from where it left off each time through the loop.